# Getting array from database

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using this class to display a calendar: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8426-PHP-Generate-HTML-to-display-month-event-calendars.html

I need to populate dates from a database like this one:

```
$calendar->events=array("2014-01-16"=>1,"2014-01-19"=>4,);
```

I got the following but is not working.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
$number = 1;    
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $response[] = array("$row['date']" => $number);
    $number++;
}
$dates = json_encode($response);
$calendar->events=array($dates);
```

The events are no showing on the calendar, but if I manually type the dates, like below, the events will show on the calendar.

```
$calendar->events=array("2014-01-16"=>1,"2014-01-19"=>4,);
```

Comment: Would you liie to show us the error message(s)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Actually, there are no error messages. The problem is that the dates are no passing to "$calendar->events=array" thus not showing on the calendar.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the values keyed by the dates, then you need something like...

```
$number = 1; 
$response = [];   
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $response[$row['date']] = $number++;
}
```

Then if you want the result encoded, you may need to use...

```
$calendar=json_encode([ 'events' => $dates]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Nothing shows on the calendar. Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you compared the output with what you are expecting.  Just saying it doesn't work isn't a way forward.